# C# How to get multiple tasks to start and then await them

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm struggling with making my tasks run. I believe they don't start and await never returns, that way my application never runs further. It's meant to process multiple data sets (known at the moment of execution) and therefore I add them using a loop, it looks this way:

```
foreach(IGrouping<enumType, Item> group in lp)
{
    Task<ProcessedItem> t = new Task<ProcessedItem>(
        () => ProcessItems(group.ToList(), group.Key));
    tasks.Add(t);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

(...)
```

And it stops at Task.WhenAll. I think they're not started at all, I have a similar code within another method, but there I pass the function to the task directly:

```
Task<ReturnType>(Func);
```

Which I believe causes the difference, I cannot pass it this way here due to parameters. How should I modify my code to make it work? Should I explicitly start each task? Wouldn't that break the await keyword if tasks finishes before the await?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think they're not started at all

You are most certainly correct. `new Task()` returns a "cold task", which is a task that hasn't started making you explicitly call `Task.Start()` on it. [The docs spell this out clearly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321321(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Rather than calling this constructor, the most common way to
>   instantiate a Task object and launch a task is by calling the static
>   `Task.Run(Action)` or `TaskFactory.StartNew(Action)` method. The only
>   advantage offered by this constructor is that it allows object
>   instantiation to be separated from task invocation.

This is one of the reasons why you shouldn't use the `Task` constructor, and instead use the factory methods, that provide you with a "hot task" which is one that is *already started*. Here, `Task.Run` would be appropriate:

```
var tasks = lp.Select(group => Task.Run(() => ProcessItems(group.ToList(), group.Key)));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Answer (score 2):

For Starting you need to call `Start()` method.And your method in which you use this fragment must be assigned with `async` keyword

```
foreach(IGrouping<enumType, Item> group in lp)
{
    Task<ProcessedItem> t = new Task<ProcessedItem>(() => ProcessItems(group.ToList(), group.Key));

    t.Start();
    tasks.Add(t);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

(...)
```

It will wait when all tasks inside then `tasks` will finish their exection

Or you can use instead of `Start()` method `Task.Run()` method

```
foreach(IGrouping<enumType, Item> group in lp)
{
    Task<ProcessedItem> t = Task.Run(() => ProcessItems(group.ToList(), group.Key));

    tasks.Add(t);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

(...)
```